# Tess4j Tesseract vs Tesseract1

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

I am not 100% sure the difference about Tesseract and Tesseract1 object in the Java api package Tess4J, anyone can explain about it?

I know Tesseract uses interface mapping, and Tesseract1 uses direct mapping. How this will change their behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same functionality with supposedly better performance.

> JNA supports a direct mapping method which can improve performance
>   substantially, approaching that of custom JNI. Method signatures are
>   the same as they would be in a JNA interface mapping, but they can be
>   any static or object methods.

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/DirectMapping.md

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of code that show the difference between using direct mapping and  interface mapping. I read the doc in the above link but not exactly sure if I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Source and examples can be found in the project's [repository](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j).